# Is it correct to write 'x plus y are z'

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

While it is correct to write 'Two and three are five' is it incorrect to write 'Two plus three are five' ? I've looked up several online dictionaries including OALD, Cambridge and Britannica but didn't find a sentence with 'x plus y are z'. On the other hand, I didn't find a rule regulating that 'x plus y are z' is incorrect English.

Comment: Why would you expect to find a "rule" specifying how to talk about mathematics in English? But to me it seems as if that is a statement about the (singular) mathematical expression "x plus y", or about its (singular) value.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20195/two-plus-two-make-makes-four?rq=1

Comment: Perhaps because people say 2 plus 3 is 5?

Comment: @ColinFine to not to write incorrect. it's also a subtopic of subject verb agreement in English classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perhaps not entirely logical, but "*two and three*" is treated as a plural expression, and takes  a plural verb. This may be because, in general, "X and Y" is a plural expression when the items are not numbers. One says "Joe and sally are married" not "is married".

On the other hand "*two plus three*" or any form of "X plus Y" is treated as singular. In general, any verbal statement of a mathematical formula is treated as singular. "X cubed times Y squared **is** twenty-three."

Anyway "two plus three are five" will be perceived as quite odd by any fluent speaker.